# init dentro del init vs atributo fuera del init

Tags: python-3.7

tengo una duda, tengo entendido que el **init** dentro de python3 se usa para crear los atributos bases de tu clase, o algo asi, entonces dentro del curso que tomo puedo ver que hay casos en los que el programador usa el init para incluir nuevos atributos en el caso de la herencia, pero en otros casos el programador lo que hace es definirlos manualmente.Aqui les va un ejemplo para que me entiendan mejor.

EJEMPLO:

## A continuación solo he creado la base de mi clase

```
class Tecnico:
  def __init__(self,nombre):
    self.nombre = nombre
```

## Ahora viene de lo que les hablo

```
#esta es la forma 1, agregar un nuevo atributo por medio del init
class Jugador(Tecnico):
  def __init__(self,nombre,dorsal):
    super().__init(nombre)
    self.dorsal = dorsal
#esta es la forma 2, digitando el nuevo atributo "manualmente"
class Jugador(Tecnico):
  dorsal = " "
```

> Y es aqui donde se me plantea la duda: ¿las 2 son y/o sirven para lo mismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `__init__` es el constructor de la clase, similar al `__construct()` de PHP y de lo que se van a encargar de inicializar las propiedades que pertenezcan a dicha clase, tan pronto esta sea instanciada.

**Ejemplo 1**

```
class Cliente:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nombre = nombre
```

Ahora durante el proceso de *instancia* la clase `Cliente` espera un valor para asignar a una propiedad llamado *nombre*

```
x = Cliente 
x.nombre = "beta"
print(x.nombre)
```

Que dará en pantalla

> beta

Para tu segundo caso donde solamente esta declarada la propiedad y se le asigna como valor una cadena de texto con un espacio en blanco.

**Ejemplo 2**

La clase `Cliente` recibe una propiedad que *ya esta inicializada* con un valor por eso el símbolo de asignación

```
class Cliente:
  nombre = "."
```

Cuando llevas a cabo la instancia de la clase, ya no es necesario asignarle un valor a dicha propiedad por que ya le fue dado dentro del cuerpo de la clase entonces solo deberás acceder a esa propiedad para imprimirlo en pantalla

```
x = Cliente 
print(x.nombre)
```

**Ejemplo 3**

```
class Cliente:
  def __init__(self, email):
    self.email = email


class ClienteGold(Cliente):
  def __init__(self, email, privilegio):
    self.email = email 
    self.privilegio = privilegio

x = ClienteGold("mail@mail.com", "con privilegios")
print(x.email)
print(x.privilegio)
```

Este ejemplo es similar en estructura al que tu tienes, revisemos:

> La clase `Cliente` posee una propiedad `email` que es inicializada a través del método constructor `__init__` y por lo tanto cuando sea inicializada se le deberá pasar como argumento uno; segundo la clase `ClienteGold` extiende o hereda de la clase padre que en este caso es `Cliente` y ahora además de la propiedad `email`, además dentro de su método constructor espera otra propiedad llamada `privilegio`.

Por lo tanto una vez que llevas a cabo la instancia de la clase `ClienteGold` deberás pasarle como argumentos 2 valores; uno para `email` y otro para `privilegio` puesto que su método constructor las va a intentar inicializar.

Para el caso anterior, en caso de omitir alguno de los argumentos esperados te va a arrojar un mensaje de error indicando que la cantidad de valores es menor a la esperada.

Comment: Gracias bro, todo me quedo muy claro

Comment: Del chulito supongo, ya le di al chulito.

Answer (score 0):

No son iguales. En el segundo caso tienes un atributo en la clase. Los objetos de esta clase pueden accesar al atributo como si fueran del mismo objeto. Sin embargo si modificas el atributo en un objeto de la clase este no afecta al atributo de otros objetos o de la clase.

```
>>>class A:
...  a = 1

>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.a
1
>>> b.a
1
>>> a.a = 2
>>> a.a
2
>>> b.a
1
>>> A.a
1
```

El que sea subclase de la clase `Tecnico` es irrelevante pues `dorsal` se implementa en la subclase.

Comment: Entendi lo  de los atributos, pero a raiz de tu ejemplo se me genero una nueva pregunta y es... cuando debo usar el init y cuando no? Porque ps el atributo o dato lo pongo y listo, pero entonces cual es la funcion o el objetivo real del __init__? -apenas estoy viendo POO en la universidad- perdon la ignorancia. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @CARLOS23GAMER7U7 El objetivo de `__init__` es inicializar los valores por objeto. Los atributos los pueden ser definidos en tiempo de ejecución al recibirlos en los parametros. Usa el init siempre que sea posible. Yo nunca he necesitado la segunda forma y no he visto código que la utilice. Con el `__init__` dejas en claro cual es tu intención.

Comment: Wow tio muchisimas gracias, lo entendi muy bien!